# Datareader error while converting string to int

Tags: c#, oledb, oledbdatareader

I am getting compile-time error at `reader.GetString`, any idea why?

Code:

```
using (var connection = new OleDbConnection())
{
    connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Sparrow vivek\Documents\Billing.accdb";
    connection.Open();
    var query = "SELECT ItemCode FROM invoice";
    using (var command = new OleDbCommand(query, connection))
    {
        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(reader.GetString("ItemCode"));
                comboBox2.Items.Add(reader.GetString("ItemCode"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `comboBox1.Items.Add(reader.GetString(0));`?

Comment: have you tried comboBox1.Items.Add(reader("ItemCode").toString());?

Comment: the best overloaded method match for system.data.common.DbDataReader.GetString(int) has some invalid arguments

Comment: "Any idea why?" Yes, you're passing invalid arguments to `DbDataReader.GetString(int)`. **Exactly as the error message says!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`OleDbDataReader.GetString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdatareader.getstring(v=vs.110).aspx) requires an input of `int`. It expects the column ordinal, not the column name.

Either use the column ordinal directly, or determine the ordinal ahead of time. You can determine the column ordinal by using `OleDbDataReader.GetOrdinal`:

```
comboBox1.Items.Add(reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("ItemCode")));
```

Since you are doing this in a loop, you could do something like this:

```
int itemCodeOrdinal = reader.GetOrdinal("ItemCode");
while (reader.Read())
{
    comboBox1.Items.Add(reader.GetString(itemCodeOrdinal));
    comboBox2.Items.Add(reader.GetString(itemCodeOrdinal));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

[`OleDbDataReader.GetString` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdatareader.getstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) takes `int` as a parameter, not `string`.

```
public override string GetString(
    int i
)
```

It takes the *zero-based* column number.

Since you get just one column, change it to;

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    comboBox1.Items.Add(reader.GetString(0));
    comboBox2.Items.Add(reader.GetString(0));
}
```

Comment: This is not `SqlDataReader`.